# Scape quotes on remote command

Tags: bash, escaping

I'm try to pass a commadn on remote server.

Command work fine on local server, but when try pass on remote server trought ssh get error for bad scpaing

```
ls -t /root/mysql/*.sql | awk 'NR>2 {system(\"rm \"" $0 \"\"")}'
```

Full comnand

```
ssh root@host -p XXX "mysqldump --opt --all-databases > /root/mysql/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).sql;ls -t /root/mysql/*.sql | awk 'NR>2 {system(\"rm \"" $0 \"\"")}'"
```

Comment: Showing the *actual* command you are trying to run (including the `ssh` piece) would be much more useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually no need to use `awk` and avoid all that quotes escaping:

```
ls -t /root/mysql/*.sql | tail -n +1 | xargs rm
```

This is *assuming your `*.sql` files don't have any whitespaces* otherwise you should use `stat` command and sort the output using `sort`.

Comment: I'm editing ask for reply another comment. Now it's marked.